# Having problem trying to export data pulled from database(PhpMyAdmin) from a collapsible using checkboxes shown on WORDPRESS

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, wordpress

I am new to PHP and trying to work on a wordpress page.

I'm trying to build a collapsible which pulls data from a table from an online database, I'm currently writing the PHP code, along with some javascript on a wordpress plugin called `snippets`.

No matter how I approach it I can't seem to find a solution, can someone please help me[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q33nn.png) the top checkbox with no collapsible is check all button.

My goal is to be able to export the information onto an excel based on the checkbox row by row. Thank you! Below is the code regarding this problem.

Also, since it's on wordpress I do not know if it's possible to link the $.ajax to another PHP page like I've seen online so I try to put everything in one snippet(one PHP file I suppose). When I click export now nothing appears the alert box comes up just fine but it won't export an excel file

```html
    <button type="button" name="export" id="export" class="btn btn-success">Export
    </button>
    </form> 
    </body>
    <p>
    <br>
    </p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll">
    
    <p>
    <br>
    </p>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.checkAll').on('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('div').find(':checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked);
        });
    });
    </script>
        
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#export').click(function(){

      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to export this?"))
      {
           var id = []; 
           $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){ id[i] = $(this).val(); }); 
        if(id.length === 0)
            {
                alert("Please Select at least one checkbox");
            }
        else
            {
                $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                data:{id:id},
                success:function()
            {
        for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++)
                {
                $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
                $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
                }
                }
                });

        }
      }
      else
      {
       return false;
      }
     });
    });

    </script>

<?php
        $output = '';
        if(isset($_POST["id"]))
        {
             foreach($_POST as $id)
             {
                $que = "SELECT * FROM Product limit 20";
                $res = mysqli_query($con, $que);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
                     {
                          $output .= '
                               <table class="table" bordered="1">  
                               <tr>  
                                   <th>id</th>  
                                   <th>Name</th>  
                                   <th>Short Description</th>  
                                   <th>Full Description</th>
                                   <th>SKU</th>
                                   <th>Order Minimun Quantity</th>
                                   <th>Order Maximum Quantity</th>
                                   <th>Categories</th>
                                   <th>Manufacturers</th>
                                   <th>PREMIX</th>
                                   <th>Medicine Name</th>
                              </tr>
                              ';
                          while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                              {
                               $output .= '
                                <tr>  
                                    <td>'.$rows["id"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$rows["Name"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$rows["Short Description"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$rows["Full Description"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$rows["SKU"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$rows["Order Minimum Quantity"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$rows["Order Maximum Quantity"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$rows["Categories"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$rows["Manufacturers"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$rows["PREMIX"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$rows["Medicine Name"].'</td>
                                </tr>
                                          ';
                              }
              $output .= '</table>';
              header('Content-Type: application/xls');
              header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');
              echo $output;
             }
        }
    }
```

```html
 <?php

    function phpexcel()
        {
         if ( defined('CBXPHPSPREADSHEET_PLUGIN_NAME') && file_exists( CBXPHPSPREADSHEET_ROOT_PATH . 'lib/vendor/autoload.php' ) ) {
        require_once( CBXPHPSPREADSHEET_ROOT_PATH . 'lib/vendor/autoload.php' );
          
        $file_name = 'Product Data_'.$date.'.xlsx';
        $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
        $product = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet, 'Product');
        
        $spreadsheet->addSheet($product, 0);
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Id');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Name');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Short Description');
        $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Full Description');
        $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'SKU');
        $sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'Order Minimum Quantity');
        $sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'Order Maximum Quantity');
        $sheet->setCellValue('H1', 'Categories');
        $sheet->setCellValue('I1', 'Manufacturers');
        $sheet->setCellValue('J1', 'PREMIX');
        $sheet->setCellValue('K1', 'Medicine Name');
            
        $query2 = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Product limit 20");
        $row = 12;
        
        while($data= mysql_fetch_object($query2)){
            $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, $data->Id);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$row, $data->Name);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$row, $data->ShortDescription);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$row, $data->FullDescription);
            $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$row, $data->SKU);
            $sheet->setCellValue('F'.$row, $data->OrderManimumQuantity);
            $sheet->setCellValue('G'.$row, $data->OrderMaximumQuantity);
            $sheet->setCellValue('H'.$row, $data->Categories);
            $sheet->setCellValue('I'.$row, $data->Manufacturers);
            $sheet->setCellValue('J'.$row, $data->PREMIX);
            $sheet->setCellValue('K'.$row, $data->MedicineName);
            $row++;
        }
        $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\";");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        $writer->save('php://output');
        exit;
    }
    }
    ?>

        <button type="button" name="test" id="test" class="btn btn-success" onclick="phpexcel()">test
        </button>
```

I tried using @Nolicasara's suggestion and this is what I am working with. I tried using creating a button to test out the function but still nothing appears. The snippet shows the code for the phpspreadsheet and the code for the button.

Comment: `mysql_query`? That looks like a typo.

Comment: how? should it be mysqli_query? or am I missing something

Comment: Yes, mysql_query has been removed years ago from the language. It doesn't exist anymore. Use PDO or if you must use mysqli

Comment: Ohhh did not know that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin https://github.com/codeboxrcodehub/cbxphpspreadsheet as library then you do own writable data to excel

```
function phpexcel() {
  if ( defined('CBXPHPSPREADSHEET_PLUGIN_NAME') && file_exists( CBXPHPSPREADSHEET_ROOT_PATH . 'lib/vendor/autoload.php' ) ) {
    //Include PHPExcel
    require_once( CBXPHPSPREADSHEET_ROOT_PATH . 'lib/vendor/autoload.php' );
    $date = current_time('dmyyHis');
    $file_name = 'HangryAppSalesNPS_'.$date.'.xlsx';
    //now take instance
    //  $objPHPExcel = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

    $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
    $pbisale = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet, 'Sales');
    $nps = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet, 'NPS');

    // Attach the "My Data" worksheet as the first worksheet in the Spreadsheet object
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($pbisale, 0);
    
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0);;
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Date');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Location ID');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Sales (w/ VAT)');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Dockets');
    $data =  get_report_data();
    $row = 2;
    foreach($data as $value){
      $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, date('d/m/yy'));
      $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$row, $value['location_id']);
      $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$row, $value['total_sale']);
      $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$row, $value['total_order']);
      $row++;
    }
    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($nps, 1);
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(1);;
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Date, time');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'LocationID');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'OrderID');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', ' NPS result(0-9)');

    $nps_data = generate_csv_nps();
    $row_nps = 2;
    foreach($nps_data as $value){
      $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$row_nps, date( "d/m/Y, H:i:s", strtotime($value['date'])));
      $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$row_nps, $value['location_id']);
      $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$row_nps, $value['order_id']);
      $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$row_nps, $value['rating']);
      $row_nps++;
    }
    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\";");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;
    // $writer->save($file_name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this and I modified it into the code edited into the post. Can you help me take a look at it. Nothing appears. Thank you so much